# WCF for remote SQL connection?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, wcf

My existing scenario is below:

I have an SQL server which resides in a main company office. The company has another branch which is 60 miles apart.

I have a WPF application installed in computers in the main office and the branch which connects to the SQL server in the main office for printing records etc.

I am specifying the connection parameters in the app.config file as below:

```
<add name="CompanyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/LabModel.csdl|res://*/LabModel.ssdl|res://*/LabModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=publicIPaddress of remote SQL here;Initial Catalog=databasename;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

My problem is that the application in the branch hangs for ever at certain times. So my question is whether its the best practice to use WCF for connecting to the remote SQL server?

Which is the best way to go about it? Is there any links which best discribes this?

Comment: Do you think the problem is that the SQL Server is not responding fast enough or something like that? You can always test it by sending `ping` messages to the SQL server and check the results afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current scenario, WCF is useless to you. If you write a server side application, that manages the database connection, you can use WCF to send the data to your clients. However that requires your client side software adapted to the use of WCF also, but in that case your clients wouldn't access the database (you would change from a two-layer architecture to a three-layer architecture). It might solve your problems, and it might introduce some other problems.

The hanging problem you describe could be caused by many things. For example you can run out of database connections, get into a deadlock (altough that transaction would be terminated by the server normally), or just simply have a lock on data being edited, and the employee using it going for a break.

It is also possible, that the problem is not with the database connection, but something in the client side code. Since I have no details, I can not tell you anything more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Picking on the wording you chose, I don't think you'll be "*connecting to the remote SQL server*" using WCF. However, you can certainly use WCF to host a service that provides your client (WPF app) with secure access to your data, though it will do so indirectly. This approach will be quite different from the approach you currently have: accessing the server directly from the WPF app.

Although I haven't used it myself, I believe one approach may be [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx). If you only need a few operations in your service (e.g. GetRecord) for printing you may also be able to just roll your own WCF service that just provides "Records" to your client app. Any introductory book or tutorial on WCF will probably get you on your way.

---

The above answers the *questions* you seemed to be asking. However, WCF doesn't solve connection issues for you: if you say "the application [...] hangs forever at certain times" you should investigate that no matter what. But that's a different question.